# Speeding up raster to point set function

Tags: raster, vector, convert, postgis-2.0, code-review

I have written the following function that takes a raster (always non-skewed) and returns a set of points. As I'm executing it millions of times in my queries, I'd like for it to be super-optimized (my queries currently take hours to complete).

Can the code below be improved?

Who knows a trick for doing this operation faster?

For my input (average cells: 38 x 21), the below runs at approx 15ms per raster (rasters are in memory).

Platform is PostGIS 2.0/PostgreSQL 9.2.4.

```SQL
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CVL_RasterToPoints
    (
        the_raster raster,
        OUT pt geometry
    ) RETURNS SETOF geometry AS
    $$
    SELECT
        ST_Translate(
            PT.pt,
            (IDX.i - 1) * ST_PixelWidth($1),
            (IDX.j - 1) * ST_PixelHeight($1)
        )
    FROM
        (SELECT
            generate_series(1, ST_Width($1)) AS i,
            generate_series(1, ST_Height($1)) AS j
        ) IDX,
        (SELECT
        ST_SetSrid(
                ST_Point(
                    ST_UpperLeftX($1) + (ST_PixelWidth($1) / 2),
                    ST_UpperLeftY($1) + (ST_PixelHeight($1) / 2)
                ),
                ST_SRID($1)
            ) as pt
        ) PT
    WHERE
        ST_Value($1,IDX.i,IDX.j) = 1
    $$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Comment: By far the best general method available to optimize raster-to-vector conversions is *don't do them.* In most cases, operations that convert or extract from rasters can be replaced by much faster (and highly vectorized) operations on the rasters themselves. Unfortunately, it's not possible to provide more specific guidance because you haven't indicated what you're really doing or why it is being done.

Comment: @whuber the final goal is to find the set of webmercator cells (using any unique id for cells, I chose center points) that a geometry intersects at a given zoom-level.

Comment: How do you want to represent that set of cells?  What will you be doing with them?

Comment: @whuber, in other words. I have a table of vector features. I want to find all webmercator cells that have more than K features intersecting, and then choose the features that intersect those cells, grouped by cell-id.

Comment: The natural raster solution to that problem is to rasterize each geometry into a binary (0-1) indicator grid and sum those grids. The fastest way I know to do that is to exploit your video hardware to draw all the features with alpha transparency: the threshold *K* will translate to a minimal opacity which can be read out of the buffer. This entire operation therefore takes only as much time as needed to render your features, which likely will be limited to the speed with which you can transmit the coordinates over your bus--perhaps well under a second total.

Comment: @whuber, It's a very high-level solution you're suggesting, but assuming that I can somehow operationalize it, I like it. By the way, I'm half-way there as I have already used a binary raster for the geometries. One potential issue is that the number of pixels grows exponentially with zoom-levels. I want to support up to around 18-20 zoom-levels.

Comment: @whuber is your solution implementable in PostGIS 2.0 (and GDAL 1.9.2)? Also I'm running on Amazon EC2. Not sure my instance has video hardware, but I could pick one that does (if such exists)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9637/discussion-between-pimin-konstantin-kefaloukos-and-whuber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Who knows a trick for doing this operation faster?

Each transaction utilises only one core. If your computer have the luxury of more cores you can use threading techniques to speed up the calculations.

Check the python's [Threading](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module

> Who knows a trick for doing this operation faster?

postgis 2.1 introduces a new function called [ST_PixelAsCentroids](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/RT_ST_PixelAsCentroids.html) which operates exactly in the same manner with your function. You might want to give it a look

Comment: I was just looking at ST_PixelAsCentroids... unfortunately I have a PostGIS 2.0 running.